# Embedding YouTube Videos in Silverstripe - Strips Fullscreen and Rel=0

Tags: tinymce, silverstripe

I'm trying to embed YouTube videos onto my Silverstripe site, using the page editor. We're having problems with two different ways of embedding.

1. Editor's Insert Media: 
   When I click the editor's "Insert Media" button I choose "From the web" and paste in the YouTube URL.  However I need to hide related videos, so to do this we need to add "&rel=0" to the end of the URL.  When I do this the "Insert Media" option doesn't work.
2. iFrame:
   So instead I tried to use the embed code provided by Google. I went to he text editor and inserted it.  The iframe works, however the editor strips off the "allowfullscreen" tag from the iframe - which means users cannot watch the video in full screen.

So I either have to show related videos, which I don't want to do.  Or I need to block users from being able to watch it in full screen mode - which again I don't want to do.

We're running on Silverstripe 3.3.

Is there any way to stop Silverstripe from stripping the allowfullscreen tag? Or to have Silverstripe still process the YouTube URL if we put rel=0 on the end?

Alternatively, does anyone know if this has this been solved in 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6?

Before posting this I have done over 45 mins of thorough searching for an answer, including through Silverstripe forums (which are now discontinued), here on Stackoverflow and the Google group. Plus I worked my way through a number of the change logs of 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6 for anything related to iframes and YouTube, but was not able to find things specific to this problem.

The TinyMCE editor in a different CMS I use does not strip out the allowfullscreen tag from iframes. So it seems specific to Silverstripe's implementation of the editor.

Comment: Since someone thought this post showed little effort of research I have updated it to state clearly the research I have done.  Over 45 mins of thorough searching for an answer, including through Silverstripe forums (which are now discontinued), Stackoverflow and the Google group. Plus I worked my way through much of the change logs of 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6 for anything related to iframes and YouTube, but was not able to find things specific to this problem. I believe it is a valid question to ask if there is any way to stop Silverstripe editor stripping the allowfullscreen tag.

Comment: I'm not the down voter but just saying that you used 45min doesn't exactly show that you actually did it . And time it takes to google a solution arent tied to each other. Just pointing out: using "tinymce silverstripe" gives fairly usable links and few of them I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct answer to your question would be to amend the tinymce config to include more attributes for the frame by setting the "extended_valid_elements"

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/#setting-options

Alternative way would be to introduce new shortcode : https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/extending/shortcodes/

Latter would be more user safe to some extend.